# Output of Multilayer Neural Networks in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I created this neural network in Matlab, and I would like to obtain the output value for an input. But there is this error:

```
No valid system or dataset was specified.
```

The input has 3 elements and then there is a fully connected layer and an output layer with 7 nodes.

```
dnn = [ 

    sequenceInputLayer(3)

    fullyConnectedLayer(20, 'WeightsInitializer','he')

    reluLayer('Name','relu')

    fullyConnectedLayer(7, 'WeightsInitializer','he')

    softmaxLayer(Name="softmax")
    ]

y = predict(dnn, [1 1 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should train that network of layers with a correct output layer configuration. Here is an example with 900x3 input - 900x1 output for traininf and 100x3 input - 100x1 output for testing. I created random 3 numbers 10000 times and use their sum as output.

```
dataX = randi(100,3,10000)/300;

trainX = dataX(:,1:9000);
testX  = dataX(:,901:10000);
trainY = sum(dataX(:,1:9000),1);
testY  = sum(dataX(:,901:10000),1);

layers = [
sequenceInputLayer(3)
fullyConnectedLayer(5)
reluLayer('Name','relu')
fullyConnectedLayer(7)
softmaxLayer(Name="softmax")
fullyConnectedLayer(1)
regressionLayer];

options = trainingOptions('adam', ...
'InitialLearnRate',0.01, ...
'MaxEpochs',1000, ...
'Shuffle','every-epoch', ...
'ValidationData',{testX,testY}, ...
'ValidationFrequency',15,'VerboseFrequency',15, ...
'Verbose',false,...
'Plots','training-progress');

net = trainNetwork(trainX,trainY,layers,options);

YPred = predict(net, testX);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I'm going to use this NN to create a Deep Q network. So, I want to use it to approximate the Q-value function of a Q-learning algorithm. In this regard, firstly I need to select actions based on the epsilon-greedy algorithm and store the information in a replay memory: 

action = argmax Q(s_t, a; ϑ) with probability 1 − epsilon;
Q is a NN and I use the current state s_t as the input of the NN. The corresponding outputs of the neural network are the Q-values of all actions at this state.


At the first iteration, I do not have training data and I want to collect data